# How many elements does $\mathbb Z_7[i]/\langle i+1\rangle$ have?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals

> How many elements have $\mathbb Z_7[i]/\langle i+1\rangle$ ?

Elements of $Z_7[i]$ are of the form $a+bi$

$i+1$ is considered as zero in the quotient;

$i+1=0\iff i=-1\iff -1=i^2=1$

does it not contain now at most $2$ elements ?

or do I have to divide $a+bi$ by $1+i$;

$a+bi=a(1+i)+b-a\equiv b-a \pmod{1+i}$

thus the elements have no imaginary part, and I can get all $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ for appropriate combinations of $a$ and $b$ ?

Comment: I'm not very fond of the notation $\Bbb Z_7[i]$ to start with. Would you be better off thinking about the ring $\Bbb Z_7[x]/\langle x^2+1,x+1\rangle$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Does it not look more complicated ?

Comment: $1=-1$ does not imply that $i=-1$ so your second approach is the right one

Comment: @inequal: Once you start talking about dividing one expression by another, you're computing with polynomials, anyhow. So what I wrote is less confusing. I don't mind writing $\Bbb Z[i]$, thinking of it as a subset of $\Bbb C$, but I'm not sure in what universe $\Bbb Z_7[i]$ makes natural sense. If you're going to manipulate symbols, you might as well do it as I suggested :D

Comment: I'm pretty confused here with the notation: are we talking here of the field with $\;7^2=49\;$ elements? I agree with Ted if this is the case, yet his last comment wasn't addressed by the OP so I cannot be sure. Also, is the use of $\;i\;$ supposed to help us "understand" that it is a root of $\;x^2+1\in\Bbb F_7[x]\;$ ?

Comment: @Timbuc $\mathbb Z_7[i]=\{a+bi:a,b\in\mathbb Z_7\}$

Comment: @inequal But with $\;i^2=-1\;$ , right ? And then yes: this is the field with $\;49\;$ elements !

Comment: @Timbuc yes you're right

Comment: Presumably $i$ is a solution of $i^2=-1$ in the extension field $\Bbb{F}_{49}$. The answer depends on what is being modded out! If it is the **ideal** generated by $1+i$, then the answer is that you get the trivial ring, because $1+i$ is a unit as a non-zero element of a field. Possibly you are to mod out the **additive group** generated by $1+i$. In that case the quotient will be a 1-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_7$ as the quotient of a 2D-space over 1D-subspace.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen It is chapter $14$ (Ideals and Factor rings) from Gallian's book, I just modified it a bit. (the original problem was $\mathbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle$

Comment: In total sympathy and agreement with @JyrkiLahtonen, I still don’t know what $\langle1+i\rangle$ is meant to be. Are we talking additive structure here or multiplicative, or, most unlikely, ideal structure?

Comment: @Lubin In the book it is the principal ideal generated by $1+i$

Comment: inequal: This may come as a surprise to you but that modification made a **huge** difference! The reason is that $\Bbb{Z}_5[i]$ is not a field but a direct product of two fields (both isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_5$). In that setting there are non-trivial ideals, and the question is much more interesting.

Comment: FYI: $\Bbb{Z}_p[i]$ is a field if and only if the prime $p\equiv3\pmod4$. When $p\equiv1\pmod4$ it is a direct product of two fields.

Comment: Oh, my! Now I see what the OP did...hahaha. In a field of characteristic $\;p=3\mod 4\,\;\;-1\;$ is **not** a square and thus what he wrote *is * a field, bot not so over characteristic $\;=1\pmod 4\;$ ...!

Comment: Rats, I'm deleting my answer, or better" re-writing it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming

$$\Bbb Z_7[i]=\Bbb F_{7^2}=\Bbb F_7[x]/\langle\,x^2+1\,\rangle =\text{ the field with $\;49\;$ elements}$$

Since a field *only* has *the* two trivial ideals (in fact, this characterizes fields among integer domains), and since clearly $\;\langle\,1+i\,\rangle\;$ is not the zero ideal, it then must be *the whole* ring, and finally

$$\Bbb F_{49}/\langle\,1+i\,\rangle\cong\{0\}$$

**Remark:** The above is a completely new, re-written answer to which the comments below do *not* apply.

Comment: @All I deleted the chain of comments as IMO all of them referred to an earlier version of this answer. If you disagree, and want the old comments visible again, just comment here and @-ping me, or flag for a moderator to help.

Comment: @Timbuc OK. but if it were $Z_5[i]$ instead, your previous answer would be valid, since $1=(1+i)(3+2i)$ and the result would be the same, do you agree ? Thanks by the way

Comment: @inequal, if it were $\;p=5\;$ my past answer would *also* be off since I made there arithmetic modulo $\;7\;$ ...And, in fact, $\;\Bbb F_5[i]=\Bbb F_5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\;$ is **not** a field, as it is in the case of the present question.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, you say that you took a question about $\Bbb F_5[i]$ and modified it. This is the core of our difficulty. By $\Bbb F_5[i]$ I’m sure the author meant $\Bbb F_5[X]/(X^2+1)$. But this ring *is not a field*. So the question makes very good sense: calling $i$ the image of $X$ in this ring, we see that $1+i$ generates a group of order $4$. Since $1+i$ is a unit in our ring, the ideal it generates is the whole ring.

The situation is entirely different when we replace “$5$” by “$7$”, for $\Bbb F_5$ already has a square root of $-1$, whereas $\Bbb F_7$ does not. So, when we take $\Bbb F_7[X]/(X^2+1)$, we are defining a field. Our textbook-author’s question is much less apposite in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost done: $\,\ {-}1\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,\color{#0a0}2\equiv 0\equiv \color{#0a0}7\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}1 =  \color{#0a0}7-3\cdot \color{#0a0}2\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, R = \color{#c00}1\cdot R = \{0\}$

**Remark** $\ $ Generally in a ring of characteristic $\,\color{#0a0}m$ if we deduce that $\,\color{#0a0}{n=0}\,$ for $\,n\,$ coprime to $\,m\,$ then, by Bezout, $\, 1 = \gcd(m,n) = j \color{#0a0}m + k \color{#0a0}n  = 0,\,$ hence, as above, the ring is trivial.

Comment: Awesome, only the iff part must be replaced by right arrows, then I solved the problem on my own, haha.

Comment: @inequal Yes, it suffices to prove $\Rightarrow$ direction.