# Cardinality of the quotient ring $\mathbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Find the cardinality of the quotient ring, $$\mathbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle$$

**My Attempt:**

Since, $$\mathbb Z_5[i]\cong Z[x]/\langle x^2+1,5\rangle$$

Hence, $$\mathbb Z_5[x]/\langle 1+i\rangle\cong \mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1,x+1,5\rangle$$

In the quotient ring we have the following,

$x^2+1=0,x+1=0$ and $5=0$, *i.e.*, $x=-1\;\; \implies 2=(-1)^2+1=0$

And, $5=0 \implies 1=0$. Thus, $\mathbb Z_5[i]/\langle 1+i\rangle\;\;=\{0+\langle 1+i\rangle\}$.

Is the above reasoning correct?

Initially, I had come across the following argument,$$1=(3+2i)(1+i)\implies 1\in \langle 1+i\rangle$$

And hence the quotient ring has just one element namely the zero element. This argument is quite good but it is not always easy to make such guesses. So I wanted to use the traditional method to find the cardinality.

Moreover, is there any different approach to the problem?

Comment: What is $i$ in this context?

Comment: @Bernard Nothing specific has been mentioned in the question. So I guess it has the usual meaning.

Comment: You can't mix a finite field like $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ with complex numbers so easily – all the more so as $-1$ has a square root in  $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$.

Comment: @Bernard As far as I remember in such problems we usually say, $x $ corresponds to $i$, and follow a similar procedure as to what I have done. Am I worng at this?

Comment: @rschwieb: I think I've fixed  the comment. For your last comment: $-1$ has two roots mod. $5$ ($\pm2)$, whence the factorisation: $x^2+1=(x-2)(x+2)$.

Comment: @Bernard You mean $(x-2)(x+2)=(x-2)\cap(x+2)$, not $(x-2, x+2)$, because the latter one is the whole ring. In fact (with that modification and the poster's agreement) it would be a good solution to post.

Comment: @Bernard I get the explanation you just gave, but can you please tell me where have I gone wrong?

Comment: @rschwieb: Oh! yes: I'll fix it. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @Naive It's not the same as the solution you gave. Currently you are both saying true things.

Comment: The problem is that we can consider, as you do, the quotient ring  $Z[x]/(x^2+1,5)$. But it is isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x^2+1)=\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/((x-2)(x+2))\simeq\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x-2)\times\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[x]/(x+2) \simeq \mathbf Z\,/\;5\,\mathbf Z \times\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$ and this one  isn't an integral domain.

Comment: @Bernard It's true: but for what step of the argument would that be a problem? I think if you go the extra step to map $1+i$ into that ring, you'll find its a unit of the product ring.

Comment: @Naive: What I find confusional in your approach is that if you consider $i $ denotes a square root of $-1$ in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$, it is one of $2$ or $-2$, hence  $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z[i]/(1+i)$ is nothing else than $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$. If you consider it denotes an external element, you obtain *in fine*  $(\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z)^2$.

Comment: @Bernard $i=\sqrt{-1}$ here.

Comment: @Sure, but is it the one in $\mathbf C$ or in $\mathbf Z/5\mathbf Z$? In my opinion, the problem is not well posed.

Comment: @Bernad $i \in \Bbb C$ is what must be considered i guess, otherwise there is nothing much in the problem as you said.

Comment: @Bernard I understand why my isomorphism was incorrect.Thank you for enlightening me. But can I say, $Z_5[i]= Z[x]/\langle x^2+1,5\rangle$, so $Z_5[x]/\langle 1+i\rangle= Z[x]/\langle x^2+1,x+1,5\rangle$ and proceed with my argument. Or is there something incorrect with that also.?

Comment: @Naive: It seems correct to me.  You can simpllify what follows observing the ideal $(x^2+1,x+1,)$ contains  $2=x^2+1+(1-x)(x+1)$, so it contains both $2$ and $5$, hence it contains $1$.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you for your valuable inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How many elements does $\mathbb Z_7[i]/\langle i+1\rangle$ have?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100352/how-many-elements-does-mathbb-z-7i-langle-i1-rangle-have)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might have analyzed it this way:

$\mathbb Z_5[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ has two maximal ideals, $(x+2)$ and $(x-2)$ since $x^2+1$ is reducible mod $5$.  If $1+x$ was not a unit in this ring, then it would be contained in one of these two ideals. But obviously $x+2-(x+1)=1$ and $x+1-(x-2)=3$ are both units, so $x+1$ is not contained in either maximal ideal, and is a unit. So the quotient is zero.

Comment: This is a good one! Thank you:)